# Can't get the size of a local image

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the height of a local image to scale it on React-Native. I tried the following code but I get `Failed to get size for image: ../../images/body.png` error.

```
scaleImg(h) {
    Image.getSize('../../images/body.png', (width, height) => {
      const scaleFactor = height / h
      const imageWidth = width / scaleFactor
      this.setState({imgWidth: imageWidth, imgHeight: h})
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but there's still no answer. For local assets you gotta use `Image.resolveAssetSource(require('./path'));` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize), you can't use `Image.getSize` on static image resources, which is what your path seems to link to.

> **static getSize(uri: string, success: function, failure?: function):** 
>   Retrieve the width and height (in pixels) of an image prior to
>   displaying it. This method can fail if the image cannot be found, or
>   fails to download.
>
> In order to retrieve the image dimensions, the image may first need to
>   be loaded or downloaded, after which it will be cached. This means
>   that in principle you could use this method to preload images, however
>   it is not optimized for that purpose, and may in future be implemented
>   in a way that does not fully load/download the image data. A proper,
>   supported way to preload images will be provided as a separate API.
>
> **Does not work for static image resources.**